# How to locate a specific page in drupal folder

Tags: drupal

Guys where is a specific page located in a drupal site. i installed drupal inside htdocs. Lets say i want to edit a page manually, where to locate it?

Comment: you want edit content or page layout? For page layout you can define file in theme directory called page-node-1.tpl.php (make it off page.tpl.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As JarodMS and Tim have mentioned Drupal is a Content Management system. It would be more appropriate to say that it is a Database driven CMS. Which means that your data as well as the configuration goes into the database (which you provide while installation).

So, lets say you create a page from the UI of Drupal and the URL is
`http://localhost/drupalsite/my-first-page`,
here, `my-first-page` is a `node`(in Drupal's term) of a content type `page` and is stored in the database. If you are familiar with Object Oriented Programming, then think of a `content type` as a *class* and `node` as its instance.

If you want to see the content of the body, you have to see it database in the `field_revision_body` table; as Drupal will not store the data on drive as a PHP (or any other) page.

P.S: In future if you have any question regarding Drupal, it is advisable to ask it on the dedicated StackExchange site Drupal Answers(URL : http://drupal.stackexchange.com). You are likely to get quick help there :-)

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is a CMS so it's content is stored in the database:  http://drupal.org/documentation/understand

Once it's installed, it is best to just poke around the content and the site, not the source code.

Comment: so there is no .php page in drupal? the content im seeing in drupal is not a .php page?

Answer (score 1):

Instruction on how to edit pages(nodes) on your Drupal 7 site.

Log into your site via www.mysite.com/user. Then go to the top menu bar >> click Content >>

You should see a view to edit or add content.

Comment: im asking if its possible to edit a page manually (by coding). ofc i know i can edit a content in that content page.

Answer (score 0):

All nodes, all users and user profiles, all information OTHER than attached files (images, for example) are stored in the **database**.

**Nodes** are stored in the "node" and "node_revisions" tables. Information about book pages parents is stored in the "book" table. Comments are stored in the "comments" table. Users are stored in the "users" and "profile_values" table. Taxonomies user several tables that begin with "term".